# Ошибка [ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external в C++ Builder 10.3

Tags: c++, c++builder

Начал изучать C++ Builder 10.3 и сразу столкнулся с непонятной ошибкой.

Пытаюсь сделать переход через MainMenu из основной формы в другие, переход на первую форму проходит без ошибок, но как только добавил функцию на переход на вторую форму при компиляции появляется эта ошибка -

> [ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'TClientsForm::FormCreate(System::TObject*)' referenced from D:\PROJECT RAD STUDIO\AUTO_PARTS_STORE\WIN64\DEBUG\CLIENTSUNIT.O

Находил похожие темы с этой ошибкой но так и не разобрался как исправить её.

Подскажите, как её исправить?

MainUnit.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "MainUnit.h"
#include "PersonalUnit.h"
#include "ClientsUnit.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TMainForm *MainForm;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMainForm::TMainForm(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMainForm::N2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
PersonalForm->ShowModal();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMainForm::N3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
ClientsForm->ShowModal();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

MainUnit.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef MainUnitH
#define MainUnitH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Menus.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TMainForm : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TMainMenu *MainMenu;
    TMenuItem *N1;
    TMenuItem *N2;
    TMenuItem *N3;
    void __fastcall N2Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall N3Click(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TMainForm(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TMainForm *MainForm;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

ClientsUnit.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "ClientsUnit.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TClientsForm *ClientsForm;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TClientsForm::TClientsForm(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

ClientsUnit.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef ClientsUnitH
#define ClientsUnitH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TClientsForm : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TClientsForm(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TClientsForm *ClientsForm;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Comment: Покажите `ClientsForm.cpp` и `ClientsForm.h`

Comment: Добавил. Они пустые, я в них ничего не писал.

Comment: А добавьте еще `ClientsUnit.dfm`

Comment: Не понимаю как ошибка может быть связана с параметрами формы

Comment: А где, по вашему, записываются ссылки на обработчики событий?

Comment: Заработало. Странно, создал новый проект и сделал всё тоже самое и заработало